# How to click multiple buttons with the same answer

Tags: button, tags, click, getelementsbyclassname

I have a page with these two types of buttons:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">This is not me</button>
```

```
<button type="button" class="emphasize btn btn-default">This is me</button>
```

If I launch this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-default");
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++)
{
inputs[i].click();
}
```

it clicks the first button of the first type, then the second of the second type and then it skips one button of the first type and one of the second type. And it restarts again with the remaining buttons.

Can I make it click instead all the buttons with the "This is not me" tag?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It's like this:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-default:not(.emphasize)")

for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
  inputs[i].click()
}
```